# css all divs vs direct child divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, children

I have this structure:

```
<div class="Root">
    <div>ddddddd</div>
    <div>
        <div>pppppppppp</div>
        <div>pppppppppp</div>
    </div>
    <div>ddddddd</div>
<div>
```

I want to put borders on the `div`s that contain `ddddddd`, and I want to set the text color on *all* `div`s to green.

There are two rules:

1. I can't add `class` attributes.
2. I have to write selectors that start with `.Root`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you add class attributes?

Comment: @thirtydot: I know how to do it with class attributes so I want to know how to do it without.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Actually I was searching this:

Selects the divs that are direct children of Root:

```
.Root > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Selects all the divs under Root:

```
.Root div {
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: Ah, what I understood was, that you wanted borders around only the second and last divs. How wrong I was :)

Comment: I agree that my structure wasn't generic enough. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 11):

Something like this?

```
.Root > :first-child, .Root > :last-child { border: 1px solid red }
.Root { color: green; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/N5qFu/1/

I would advise you to go through this: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score -3):

```
.root {
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Why are you not declaring class /id for other divs?