# sass style for immediate consequence div

Tags: html, css, sass

For example, let's say my code looks like below.
Same from [css all divs vs direct child divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529063/css-all-divs-vs-direct-child-divs) but, need in SASS.

```
<div class="Root">
    <div>ddddddd</div>
    <div>
        <div>pppppppppp</div>
        <div>pppppppppp</div>
    </div>
    <div>ddddddd</div>
</div>
```

I want to put borders on the divs that contain ddddddd, and I want to set the text color on all divs to green.

There are two rules:

I can't add class attributes.
I have to write selectors that start with .Root.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It could be like this (SASS):

```
.Root 
  padding: 1em
  color: green
  > div:not(:nth-of-type(2))
    border: 1px solid red
```

which compiles to:

```css
.Root {
  padding: 1em;
  color: green;
}
.Root > div:not(:nth-of-type(2)) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Root">
    <div>ddddddd</div>
    <div>
        <div>pppppppppp</div>
        <div>pppppppppp</div>
    </div>
    <div>ddddddd</div>
</div>
```

Also the last `<div>` should be `</div>`.

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much :)